# Get Application Path of offending DLL from Exception

Tags: c#, logging, path, assemblies

We currently have a simple Log class that can take in an exception.  In our business logic if we happen to need a try/catch around a specific set of code, we log the exception and then rethrow it.  The problem is that our Log class is in a common dll and when it writes the log I want to be able to also grab the path of the offending code (e.g. "D:\application\libraries").  Is there a simple way to do this without always having to pass in the executing assembly path to the logger each time?

Edit: Forgot to mention we're using C# 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` inside your log method?

Comment: Seems to work although I will have to do some string formatting to make it look "pretty" but it does get the job done. Thanks.